# Filter pandas pandas dataframe by comparing rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Df with for test samples and some of them were redone (redo) now I want to filter only the original ones

```
col
a
b
a_redo
b_redo
c
d
e
f
g
g_redo
```

out

```
col
a
b
g
```

this is the code that I use to filter only redo sample (_L _Q  _S are redo prefix)

```
sample[sample['col'].str.contains("_L|_Q|_S")]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter only `redo` values by [`Series.str.endswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html), remove it by [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) and then filter original values in column by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
vals = sample.loc[sample['col'].str.endswith("redo"), 'col'].str.replace('_redo','')
df = sample[sample['col'].isin(vals)]
print (df)
  col
0   a
1   b
8   g
```

With your mask:

```
vals = sample.loc[sample['col'].str.contains("_L|_Q|_S"), 'col'].str.replace("_L|_Q|_S",'')
df = sample[sample['col'].isin(vals)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
mask_redo = sample['col'].str.contains("_L|_Q|_S")
mask_orig = - mask_redo
sample_orig = sample.loc[mask_orig]
```

Basically, by placing minus sign before the mask that selects strings containing the redo suffixes, you invert the selection: you now have a mask that selects strings that do not contain redo suffixes, i.e. your original samples.